# What does the "forkReserve" property do when using grails.project.fork in BuildConfig.groovy?

Tags: grails

What does the forkReserve property do when using grails.project.fork in BuildConfig.groovy, and in what circumstances would it need to be modified?

Default grails 2.4.5 BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]
```

The value is not in the documentation.

Here is the default entry based on the docs.

```
grails.project.fork = [
   test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true], // configure settings for the test-app JVM
   run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256], // configure settings for the run-app JVM
   war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256], // configure settings for the run-war JVM
   console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]// configure settings for the Console UI JVM
]
```

Comment: Not a lot on that try enabling debugging and setting true as well as false. Presume it tries to preserve a limit for the fork. Newer grails has moved away from that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `forkReserve` setting will start an additional "reserve" JVM in the background that is in an idle state waiting. When you then restart the application this idle JVM will be used to run the application, thus avoiding the cost of starting a new JVM from fresh.

In other words, it provides a small optimisation to startup time for application restarts, that you may or may not want to take advantage of.

Comment: What is the default value for forkReserve?  If true why does the run command not want to take advantage of the small optimization for restarts by default?  Is the only downside that an extra JVM is sitting out there consuming memory and some cpu cycles?  (I feel like a little kid asking "Why?  Why?  Why?")

Comment: Yes the disadvantage is the extra memory requirements, hence it is disabled by default

Comment: Thanks for the information.  It sounds like there isn't really any valid reason for a mere mortal to touch that setting.  If you have any real life examples where someone needed to modify that setting it could be educational.